# Find a tag with multiple classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm curious how could I find a tag using `BeautifulSoup`, if it's class has multiple names separated by space so there are multiple classes in fact in this tag.

For example:

```
<div class="col-md-8 middle-content>
```

If I use `css selector` it would be: `div.col-md-8.middle-content` I think but how to find it using `soup.find()`?

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like this:

```
soup.find('div', {'class': "col-md-8 middle-content"})
```

Comment: Be aware that at least with BS version 4.7.1 the given order of the classes is mandatory! You won't find elements with `middle-content col-md-8` with the given command.